I cannot ask questions on OS. 15.7.1
That happens on iPad 6, OS 15.7.1. For both the site and this meta.
The „review your question“ button is irresponsive. No difference observed between safari and freshly updated chrome on said iPad.
I am now posting from an Android phone.
It appears, I can edit questions just fine on said iPad, once I have posted them from Android.
Edit: the bug persists (Fr. March 1)

Would that be iPadOS 15.7.1 then? I believe iOS is mobile only.

@Mou某 I guess so. It only gives a number. I will try to attach a screen shot.
